# Best way to transform cell data in matlab to dataframe in python

Tags: python, matlab

I have a weird strutured cell in matlab that I need to analyse. It consists of 18 subjects and 8 experiments

[the cell in matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbLSr.png)

I need to transform that into a dataframe that resembles this

```
subject: Francis, putin, joanne
experiment: 1_1, 1_2, 1_3
data: 3, 4, 5,...
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this? my problem if that using load mat kind of losses some of my data, I have tried to do this

```
mat= loadmat('/content/pROIALL.mat')    
mat = {k:v for k, v in mat.items() if k[0] != '_'}
data = pd.DataFrame({k: pd.Series(v[0]) for k, v in mat.items()})
```

Comment: [Write the cell to a CSV file](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/70018-how-to-write-cell-array-into-a-csv-file) and then load it using Pandas in Python.

Comment: Hey Guys! 
The main problem that I was having was related to the Matlab data structure. Each time series cell was saved as a 'char', and it was tough to extract from there. 
The way I solved it was by passing to a double array using cell2mat(). And from there it is quite easier to work.